# HTML text over image while maintaining background image clickability

Tags: html, css, image, z-index

on my website I have a `background` button that is "hidden" (it blends in with the `background`, but is secretly a `button`) and it was working fine until I edited my page with text on it.

On some monitors the text covers the image, but not completely - there is space below and beside it where the image peeks through.

However, this makes the image overlap the text, breaking the illusion. Setting the `z-index` to `-1` makes it go behind the text, but makes it unable to be clicked.

Is there any way to make something behind text clickable while staying behind text?

[image]

The "eye" between the columns is the hidden image.

Current code for image:

```
<a href= "/aboutme/vision.html">
  <img style="position:absolute; top:354px; left:975px; width:108px; height:32px; z-index:-1" src="eye.png">
</a>
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest overlaying the text like this since it will show up incorrectly at different browser dimensions. Make an outer div that has a background of the image you want and then inside the div you can put the text, button, etc and set the click event onto the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rearranged the website layout to use a clickable `div` instead of an image, and now it works on click even if text is over it. I then put it in a nested `div` which is the size of the entire window, so the links never get misaligned based on window size:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="bodyDiv">
   <div class="secret" style="position:relative; top:770px; left:1168px; width:108px; height:32px; background-color:black;" onclick="location.href='/aboutme/vision.html'"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#bodyDiv {
        background-image: url("homebackgroundsmall.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        height: 1200px;
        width: 1684px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -842px;
      }
```

The downside to this is that there is no mouse change on hover, making the secrets overly hidden. To personally fix this to make it more obvious, I made the `.secret` class so on hover the background portion of the div fades out by increasing the background opacity to 1 (which is black):

**CSS**:

```
.secret {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
      }
.secret:hover {
        opacity: 1;
      }
```